# Orientation change changes spinner's position

Tags: android, spinner, screen-orientation

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809434/can-my-spinners-entries-depend-on-another-spinners-position), I got an answer as to how to make the position of one spinner change the entries of another. But now as I am debugging it on my phone, I realize, that if I rotate the screen, the first spinner stays right, but the second two change their position back to 0. I don't think I want to completely handle the orientation change on my own, so how do I get around this?

Comment: It does kind of make sense that this happens, the OS may reconstruct the activity's state when the orientation changes, but changing the first spinner's position changes the adapters of the next two, thus resetting their position back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

[Setting the background of an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764086/setting-the-background-of-an-activity/6764220#6764220)

See this question here, use the code in the answer and modify orientation of the spinners for your needs.

Comment: But won't that make me handle all of the spinners' positions, the text in the EditText, and all the elements in a dynamically-populated ListView?
Oh, and by position I do mean the selected item index, not layout position.

Comment: Ow..Sorry..I got it layout position. Try repopulating the spinners with existing data. Then you'll dont need to deal with scrambled positions.